# How to find the minimum of a vector A and index all the minimum values without using inbuilt function such as 'find' 'min' and recall duplicates too?

Tags: matlab, indexing, min

My A = [10 1 6 8 2 3 1 3]. As we can see the minimum value is 1 and is seen twice at index 2 and 7.

My MATLAB code is below:

```
function [m,im] = myMinInd(A)
m = A(1);
im = 1;
    for i = 2:length(A)
        if A(i) < m
            m = A(i);
            im = i;
        end
    end
end
```

```
>> A
A =
    10     1     6     8     2     3     1     3
>> [m,im] = myMinInd(A)
m =
     1
im =
     2
```

My index only shows the first time the '1' appears and not the second time. Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for` loop, you need to handle cases where `A(i) == m`. For example, like this:

```matlab
function [m,im] = myMinInd(A)
m = A(1);
im = 1;
    for i = 2:length(A)
        if A(i) < m
            m = A(i);
            im = i;
        elseif A(i) == m
            im = [im,i];
        end
    end
end
```

This causes the output `im` to be a row vector containing the indices of all minimum values.